# How to make 3 columns appear as 2 half width + 1 full width underneath on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, scss-mixins

Thanks for taking a look.

Using a modified version of Foundation.css from a custom BigCommerce theme, I have 3 columns displaying left-to-right as expected, but I would like the 3rd column to be pushed underneath the first 2 on mobile.

So on desktop/tablet it should be:

```
.columns {
  @include grid-column(4);
}
```

Mobile should look something like this:

```
.columns {
  @include grid-column(6);
  &.third-column {
    @include grid-column(12);
  }
}
```

Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
.footer-column-row {
        @include grid-row;
        @include breakpoint(medium) {
            .footer-column {
                @include grid-column(4);
            }
        }
        @include breakpoint(small) {
            .footer-column {
                @include grid-column(6);
                    &.social-links {
                        @include grid-column(12);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`.social-links` is the 3rd column, the one I need to go below the other two on mobile.
I took out all the other styling (colors, etc) because it's not necessary here.

I was thinking I might need to nest some columns/rows inside of each other, or something similar, but I also assumed there might be a less messy solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Could you please add the markup as well? Without content it would be fine.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="grid-container footer">
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-margin-x">

             <hr>


        <div class="cell medium-4" small-offset-1"">
        <a class="button small primary imgCtr" href="tel:+15195551212" title="Click to Dial">Telephone: (519) 555-1212 <i class="fi-telephone"></i></a></div>
        <div class="cell medium-4" small-offset-1"">
        <a class="button small primary imgCtr" href="tel:+15195551212" title="Click to Dial">Fax: (519) 555-1212 <i class="fi-page"></i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="cell medium-4" small-offset-1"">
        <a class="button small primary imgCtr" href="mailto:office@anymail.com">Email Office  <i class="fi-page"></i></a>
         </div>


<div class="cell medium-12 ">
             <div class="media-object align-center">
              <div class="media-object-section middle">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="assets/logos/PowerLogo.jpg" width="50">
                </div>
              </div>
          <div class="media-object-section">
            <p><span class="companyTitle">ABC Marketing Inc.</span><br>
            123 Main<br>
                Hometown, ON  A1B 2C3<br>
                Canada
            </p>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /media object -->
    </div><!-- /cell -->
</div>
</div>
```